# System variable not updated in R

Tags: r

Hi I just updated my JAVA_HOME in windows 10 system using control panel way.

Click Start --> Control Panel --> User Accounts --> Change my environmental variables

Then add new var JAVA_HOME; value:D:JAVA/

However when I using Sys.getenv() in R console it is not showed up.

I knew I could using Renviron.site or Renviron to set the sys variable

I want to know how to get my system changes updated by R and if not automatically, how could I force R to do that.

I am also very happy to know how r created those system env variables (even I didn't have Renviron.site and/or Renviron files)

================================================================

After restart computer, the env variable get updated.
While it is still puzzling that window's env variable and R's env variable are different, they have many conflicts.

Comment: @user16320675 I think so, so I removed java tags; I also added the way for me to add system environment var in windows system